# is it possible to have StoryBoard Primary Design RTL?

Tags: ios, xcode, right-to-left

I have an application to develop only for RTL language, I have gone with documentation but did not found any way to design storyboard as RTL as my primary language.

I don't have any LTR language support. Is it possible to Design all my layout as RTL as my primary language?

Can anyone suggest me how it's possible?

I don't want to prefer the design in LRT and then set "Applelanguages" as any of RTL.

Thank you

Comment: plaeace refur this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. You should file a bug report at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) requesting this.

Also, for the record—you shouldn't have to use AppleLanguages anywhere. If you're being told to change NSUserDefaults, you're probably doing it wrong.